# How to Pack Different Types of Data Together into Binary Data with Python

Tags: python, c, networking

Suppose there is a user-defined protocol as below:

```
The protocol:

 ------------- ------------- ---------------- -----------------
|   Seqno.    |      ip     |       port     |    user name    |
| int, 4 bytes| int, 4 bytes| short, 2 bytes | string, 50 bytes|


the [user name] field stores a string ending with zero,    
if the string length is less than 50 bytes, padding with zeros.
```

Usually I will pack these fields in C language like this:

```
//Pseudo code
buffer = new char[60];
memset(buffer, 0, 60);

memcpy(buffer, &htonl(Seqno), 4);
memcpy(buffer+4, &htonl(ip), 4);
memcpy(buffer+4, &htons(port), 2);
memcpy(buffer+2, Usrname.c_str(), Usrname.length() + 1);
```

But how can we pack the protocol data in python? I am new to python.

Comment: Take a look at [struct packing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html):

```
import struct

binary_value = struct.pack('!2IH50s', seqno, ip, port, usrname)
```

This packs 2 4-byte unsigned integers, a 2-byte unsigned short and a 50-byte string into 60 bytes with network (big-endian) byte ordering. The string will be padded out with nulls to make up the length:

```
>>> import struct
>>> seqno = 42
>>> ip = 0xc6fcce10
>>> port = 80
>>> usrname = 'Martijn Pieters'
>>> struct.pack('!2IH50s', seqno, ip, port, usrname)
'\x00\x00\x00*\xc6\xfc\xce\x10\x00PMartijn Pieters\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Python's string representation uses ASCII characters for any bytes in the ASCII printable range, `\xhh` for most other byte points, so the `42` became `\x00\x00\x00*`.

Comment: I want the seqno, ip and port to be network byte order (big endian, we use htonl to translate in c language), how to do this?

Comment: @Steve: see the [*Byte Order, Size and Alignment* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment); replace the `=` with `!`.